# For Mantis, can the DEFECT TYPE field be displayed in the grid?

Tags: manual-testing

I m using Bug tracking tool Mantis. At times i need to view the issues on the basis of Defect type. Can I have this in the GRID to make things easier and up going.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes! you can add Defect Type. I have worked on Mantis and my manager added this field. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do!

Answer (score 1):

Is 'Defect Type' custom field? If is, read this topic, it should help:
https://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=8621

(I'm sorry I have no enough reputation to comment)

Answer (score 0):

In our QA Services company we are using Mantis. Below are the steps to Add/Edit a new custom field:

1. The logged in user needs $g_manage_custom_fields_threshold access level.
2. Select "Manage" from the main menu.
3. Select "Manage Custom Fields" from the management menu.
4. In case of edit, click on the name of an existing custom field to edit its information.
5. In case of adding a new one, enter the name of the new custom field then click "New Custom Field".

Note: Added custom fields will not show up in any of the issues until the added custom field is linked to the appropriate projects.

More Information can be found at

https://www.mantisbt.org/manual/admin.customize.html

http://www.guru99.com/mantis-bug-tracker-tutorial.html

Comment: Bhakti is asking about showing the field in the report grid and not actually adding a custom field in Mantis altogether.